# Organic Groups -- Load group from gid

Tags: organic-groups

This seems like it should be a simple operation, but I must be completely blind because I can't find anything about it in the API docs at http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/7.

I have a $gid. I need to check if it really is the gid of a valid group, and have access to the group information if it is.

I did find an old post somewhere saying to use og_load(), but that is out of date -- that function does not exist in the current API. Nor can I find a function with similar functionality.

There has to be a simple way to do this; it's hardly an outlier use-case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `group_load` anymore! Use `node_load` instead. You gid is equivalent to nid.

Comment: With node_load .. It dosn't display if current user (subscribe or not) ..

Answer (score 0):

you could use og_get_group() http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/og/og.module/function/og_get_group/7 API to get the og group. It Return a loaded group entity if exists or create a new one.

Comment: Actually, that's the 7.x 1.0 API. That function no longer exists in the 7.x 2.0 API.